# Jones polynomial of 2-knots

Tags: knot-theory, 2-knots

Question: is it possible to define the Jones polynomial for knotted surfaces (or $S^2$ for simplicity) in $R^4$?

Jones polynomial has several definitions (see [How many definitions are there of the Jones polynomial?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67712/how-many-definitions-are-there-of-the-jones-polynomial)). Is there any one of them (such as the skein relation along double curves or representations of 2-braids) can be generalized to define the Jones polynomial of 2-knots? One of the motivation of this question is, if we can define the Jones polynomial for 2-knots, maybe we can use it to determine the minimal number of triple points of the 'alternating' 2-knot diagram.

Comment: As far as I know there's no natural and direct way to extend a Jones polynomial definition from 1-knots to 2-knots.   But as you've stated it, this is a little poorly-defined as far as questions go.  Would you want the Jones polynomial of a 2-knot to relate to the Jones polynomial of a 1-knot in any way?

Comment: Thanks for Budney's reply. I do not want the Jones polynomial of a 2-knot relate to the Jones polynomial of a 1-knot. In fact I want to know whether there exists an invariant of 2-knot which can determine the minimal number of triple points. Since Jones polynomial tells us that reduced alternating knot diagram has minimal crossing number. I do not know whether this can be generalized to 2-knots. The only approach I know to the minimal triple points of a knotted surface diagram is the quandle 3-cocycle invariants.

Comment: It's not clear to me polynomial invariants are of much use to 2-knot theory.  Relatively little is known about the connect-sum operation for 2-knots at this point.